# object initalisation inside object params (constructer)

Tags: c++

Hello I try to pass objects of same type class constructer and i like to save it as tuple inside the class.

So I have this code for it:

```
class endpoint_keys_impl {
public:
    endpoint_keys_impl() = default;

    template<typename ...PO>
    explicit endpoint_keys_impl(PO... properties) : keys(std::tuple(properties)...) {}
    
private:
    std::tuple<PropertyObject> keys;
};
```

That constructs a tuple from the constructer params of type PropertyObject.

PropertyObject == property

So i can construct this with:

```
endpoint_keys_impl test { property("prop1"), property("prop2") };
```

It worked correctly and i used two subclasses like this:

```
struct websocket_endpoint_keys : public endpoint_keys_impl {
    websocket_endpoint_keys() = default;

    template<typename ...PO>
    explicit websocket_endpoint_keys(PO... properties) : endpoint_keys_impl(properties...) {};
};
```

and a other one for rest_endpoint_keys.

I used booth classes in a class named data_endpoint:

```
template <typename T>
class data_endpoint {
public:
    data_endpoint(std::string  path, rest_endpoint_keys rest_keys, websocket_endpoint_keys websocket_keys)
    : _internal_rest_keys(std::move(rest_keys)),
      _internal_websocket_keys(std::move(websocket_keys)),
      path(std::move(path)) {};
};
```

Now, when i try to init these class with more as one propertry, i get an error, why?

```
data_endpoint<sometype> endpoint
        {"symbols",
            rest_endpoint_keys {
                property("prop1"),
                property("prop2")
            },

            websocket_endpoint_keys {
                property("prop1"),
                property("prop2")
            }
        };
```

EDIT:

I think the problem is that the tuple in the endpoint_keys_impl only has one Type. But when i has more items then the tuple should have std::tuple<PropertyObject, PropertyObject>.

There exist a way to generate the std::tuple in that class without parameterize all until the data_endpoint class? (The type is known, but i need the count of it and a generate for the tuple)

Comment: Please show the exact error message you get.

Comment: The error is (only when I init two properties):

`In instantiation of function template specialization 'websocket_endpoint_keys::websocket_endpoint_keys<PropertyImpl<binance::symbol_info_t, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>>, PropertyImpl<binance::symbol_info_t, STATUS_E>>' no matching constructor for initialization of 'endpoint_keys_impl'`

Comment: Can nobody help me?